# Compiling Java from CMD/Powershell fails

Tags: java, windows, cmd, compiler-errors, javac

I have installed JDK already on my Windows10

Now, I am trying to run the code from cmd or PowerShell.

I have created two java files, respectively TestClass.java, and Test1.java

both of them have the same code inside:

```
public class TestClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello");
     }
}
```

When I navigate to the containing folder and run `javac TestClass.java`; it compiles; when I run `java TestClass, I got error message saying "Error: Could not find or load the main class TestClass.class"

Can anyone help me point out where the problem maybe?

Comment: To compile the command is `javac <file_name>` and the to run `java <file_name>`

Comment: You want to be compiling your java source file, e.g. `javac Test.java`

Comment: You can't compile a `.class` file as it's already compiled. Source files end in `.java`.

Comment: @AnkushPandit You should give the main _class name_, not the file name, when executing `java` (or use `-jar <jar_file>`, or `--module <module>/<main-class>`).

Comment: @Slaw That's right, but I thought that he knew that 'main' class is to be run

Comment: @AnkushPandit I wanted to clarify because you said "`java <file_name>`". That would indicate doing something like `java com/example/foo/Main.class` is the correct command , but the actually correct command would be `java com.example.foo.Main`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your reply. You're correct. to compile it should be javac file.java (source file) ; then it'll generate file.class (bitcode file); I have been literally trying to fix this porblem for hours by now. earlier to see if I can compile, I deleted "bitcode file", apparently my brain was not functionaing well at that momement.

Comment: @AnkushPandit I added additional info on the original post, please check and let me know.

Comment: @Slaw: I've been trying to fix this issue for hours, I guess when I post the original question I was not tbe best myself. Added some more info to the question. feel free to check it and let me know if you happen to have the answer how to fix this issue. Thank you

Comment: As I mentioned, it's `java <main-class-name>`, not `java <file-name>`. Try `javac TestClass.java` followed by `java TestClass`.

Comment: @Slaw: here is what I tried after saw your message: >>[PS C:\Users\myUser\Desktop> javac .\TestClass.java
PS C:\Users\myUser\Desktop> java .\TestClass.class
Error: Could not find or load main class .\TestClass.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\TestClass/class
PS C:\Users\myUser\Desktop>]<< now it became a different exception. as the screenshot in the previous post indicates, I had the environment variable set up, but may have been setup improperly. don't know what the problem is

Comment: @Slaw: I tried to make my comment more human readable, but it seems like I can't go to the next line, or a lot of other stuff. basically I went to the folder where I saved the .java files, then ran the command <javac TestClass.java> ; and then when I ran <java TestClass.class> (it automatically adds the extension in Windows, which you probably know) ; I got the [Error: Could not find or load main class .\TestClass.class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /\TestClass/class] error

Comment: _Again, do not include the_ `.class` _extension when executing_ `java`. That's not how the tool works. It accepts a fully qualified class name, **not** a file path. Simply do `java TestClass` and see if that works.

Comment: @Slaw: I tried, this time it's giving me "Error: Could not find or load main class TestClass" error. Since I've been trying to fix this sooner so that I can actually use notepad to practise coding. I might have changed something else, but I don't know what caused this. In order to make it less confusing for you,I'll add some more info in at the end of my original post. Thank you

Comment: @elysium: please don't give details like error messages and commands you tried in the comments, they are essentially unreadable in here, instead edit your question to include them. As a next step, please post 1. the *exact* code of the `TestClass` you tried to compile (most importantly the header with any `package`) statements, 2. the *exact path* where it lies, 3. which commands you tried to execute to compile them and what directory you were in when you executed them and 4. the exact output of those commands (copy-paste, not rephrased).

Comment: @JoachimSauer: I went to the folder where I saved the .java files. // 1. ran javac TestClass.java file; got error message // before I could run javac TestClass.java file, I was having issue with running java TestClass.class (bytecode file); but after trying to fixed it by doing whatever I see online; it stopped compiling altogether. // I feel like it should be a problem with env _variables, but don't know what the issue is

Comment: I repeat: *Please don't give details like error messages and commands you tried in the comments, they are essentially unreadable in here, instead edit your question to include them.*

Comment: Your question seems to be completely outdated, please edit it to show what your current code is and what the results of running javac and java are.

Comment: The command `java TestClass` should never produce the error message `Error: Could not find or load the main class TestClass.class`. That error message suggests that you actually executed `java TestClass.class` (which would be wrong!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem fixed.

a. (after removed anything Java related software (from Oracle) but one STL Java version)
b. I went ahead and re-map the path to Java folder in a proper way (both JAVA_HOME and under  environment path)
c. rebooted the computer. (in my case it didn't work out the first time, but it may work for you at once, or who knows even without rebooting)

then when I ran <java -version> and <javac -version>, it worked fine.

Thank you for everyone who's kindly provided some tips how to resolve the issue!